# Deleting jobs from Job History on Xerox Workcentre Pro 123

Tags: printer, fax

How do you delete one or more fax jobs from the Job History on a Xerox Workcentre Pro 123?  The Xerox Workcentre Pro 123 is a combination copier, printer, scanner and fax machine, and it keeps a history of the numbers dialed for sending faxes, including any long distance access codes that were dialed.  In order to keep these access codes private, I'd like to remove these jobs from the job history, or alternatively clear the entire job history. Unfortunately the User Guide and the Quick Reference Guide don't explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [Xerox Support](http://www.support.xerox.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/WEBCGI.EXE?St=50,E=0000000002027088638,K=2133,Sxi=1,Case=obj(6110)) website it specifically mentions that it's not possible to do, so I don't think there will be any way to do it

> The list of jobs displayed on the
>   Completed Jobs tab on the Job Status
>   screen will display up to the last 200
>   jobs the machine has processed. This
>   includes copy, print, scan, or fax
>   jobs. These jobs cannot be deleted;
>   however, the status of these jobs can
>   be checked. A status of "Completed",
>   "Completed - Error", or "Canceled"
>   will be displayed for each job.

It may be worth giving Xerox customer care centre a ring, they've always been pretty helpful with any software issues we've had, even if it is just to tell you it's not possible.